# No Index shown in Algolia dashboard despite WordPress setting shows index created , Why?

Tags: wordpress, indexing, algolia

I downloaded the latest version of WordPress plugin and Installed it. Then I pasted three keys required under setting. After that indexing was tried.
However, I find that the Aloglia dashboard shows No Index .

Am I doing something wrong or plugin is not connecting.

I have latest versions of WordPress

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its a support request for a plugin and should be asked on the plugin support page.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest version of the plugin, 0.2.5 right now, here are the required steps to index your content:

1. Add your App ID, Search API key and Admin API key on the settings page,
2. Ensure that when you save the page, you get a success message,
3. Go turn on the logging on the 'Logs' page (this is optional but helps debugging)
4. Check some indices on the 'Indexing page' and hit the save button

From there the indexation tasks should start being queued and handled.
You have to wait a few seconds to see the queue status refreshes.

You can also check your logs to see what happened.

If you have errors in your logs, please post them as comment.

There are 2 common issues that would make your WordPress instance not able to contact Algolia servers:

1. Your server has no access to the network,
2. Your are using docker in a configuration that does not allow the server to access itself when calling the url of your website.

More detailed steps to get the search plugin for WordPress up and running can be found in the official documentation of [Algolia Search plugin for WordPress](https://community.algolia.com/wordpress/installation.html).

Comment: The plugin can now be installed directly from the WordPress plugins section because we are listed here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-by-algolia-instant-relevant-results/ ;)